# laravel pass parameter by href as variable instead of Request object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a link pass an `id` to a controller. The first scenario with `$id` paramter in contrller function it throws `Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ProductController::edit()` error. when I change it to request it works what I expected, but I dont understand why laravel cant map id in query string to varaible $id in controller function??

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)//this throws missing argument exception, if I change $id to Request $request it works..
{
    return view('frontend.product.create');
}
```

**Blade**

```
<a data href="{{ route('product.edit',['id'=>$product->id]) }}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('product/edit', ['uses' => 'ProductController@edit', 'as'=>'product.edit']);
```

EDITED
here are the changes I make and the result:
**Routes**

```
  Route::get('product/edit/{id}', ['uses' => 'ProductController@edit', 'as'=>'product.edit']);
```

result:

```
NotFoundHttpException in compiled.php line 8277:
in compiled.php line 8277
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7511
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7476
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 7468
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in compiled.php line 2307
...
```

as you see it  expects Request object but I want to send it just a varible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace {id} in route with the $product->id value when you are making HTTP GET request.

Example :-

Suppose if your product id is 334455, then the url when making request will be
https://www.yoursitename.com/product/edit/334455

Try this and it will work.

Comment: Yes its binded with that way, but actually I wanted to do this without change route. I mean: "Route::get('product/edit',..)" and use blade with parameter name:"<a data href="{{ route('product.edit',['id'=>$product->id])..." is it possible ?

Comment: you can use Optional Parameters in route as

Route::get('product/edit/{id?}', ['uses' => 'ProductController@edit', 'as'=>'product.edit']);

just add ? in {id?}

and then you can access the route with and without parameter.
you can use if else conditions for this in controller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter to your routes:

```php
Route::get(
    'product/edit/{id}', // <-- Add this
    ['uses' => 'ProductController@edit', 'as'=>'product.edit']
);
```

Comment: Ty for answer but this time it throws "NotFoundHttpException".

Comment: Did you check to see whether the route with such an ID even exists?